# How can I change validation for registration form

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, form-validation, register

I want to change the firstname and lastname field validation in registration form.

I want first name and last name should be only characters with maxlength 15.

And in which file I can find the code for first name and last name.

How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change in below files for validation of firstname and last name

Copy file from

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml**

to

**app/design/frontend/Your-Theme/Your-Package/template/customer/widget/name.phtml**

change as per your requirement

add validation in

**js/prototype/validation.js**

I suggest you to add validation add your own class to that field and create validation for it.

Answer (score 0):

To put desired validation on input fields. You can do following changes.

Copy file from **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml**
to
**app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/customer/widget/name.phtml**

Add `maxlength="15"` attribute in your input tag like following and Add css class `validate-length maximum-length-15` in your firstname and lastname input tags.

Add following code in **app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/customer/widget/name.phtml** file :

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->getContainerClassName()?>">
<?php if ($this->showPrefix()): ?>
    <div class="field name-prefix">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>"<?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <?php if ($this->getPrefixOptions() === false): ?>
                <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getPrefix()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
            <?php else: ?>
                <select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix')?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>" class="<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>
                <?php foreach ($this->getPrefixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $_option?>"<?php if ($this->getObject()->getPrefix()==$_option):?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_option)?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <div class="field name-firstname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('firstname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?>" maxlength="15" class="input-text validate-length maximum-length-15 <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>
<?php if ($this->showMiddlename()): ?>
<?php $isMiddlenameRequired = $this->isMiddlenameRequired(); ?>
    <div class="field name-middlename">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>"<?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' class="required"' : '' ?>><?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? '<em>*</em>' : '' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('middlename')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('middlename') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <div class="field name-lastname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname')?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('lastname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('lastname')) ?>" maxlength="15" class="input-text validate-length maximum-length-15 <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>
<?php if ($this->showSuffix()): ?>
    <div class="field name-suffix">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix')?>"<?php if ($this->isSuffixRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isSuffixRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('suffix') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
        <?php if ($this->getSuffixOptions() === false): ?>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('suffix')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getSuffix()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('suffix')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        <?php else: ?>
            <select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('suffix')?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getStoreLabel('suffix')) ?>" class="<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>
            <?php foreach ($this->getSuffixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $_option?>"<?php if ($this->getObject()->getSuffix()==$_option):?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_option)?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: In which file I need to change? I am not able to find that firstname and lastname field in file

Comment: First tell: what you want to do?. Update your question with proper requirements

Comment: @Jatin Try my code. It will work.